# SRAM DoubleTap - attempting to shift down in lowest gear

Tags: shifter, sram

My bike has a shifter with the SRAM DoubleTap mechanism, where you push it over one click to shift up and two clicks to shift down. When you're in the lowest gear, it only allows you to push it over one click (so you have to shift up).

The problem arises when I'm climbing a hill without realizing I'm in the lowest gear. When I go to shift down a gear, I can't and have to shift up instead. Is there a trick to "cancel" the shift, or is the only way to keep track of my current gear in my head?

Components:

- Shifter: SRAM Rival 22 Mechanical Shifters (SB-RIV-B1)
- Rear derailleur: SRAM Rival 1 Rear Derailleur (RD-RIV-1-A2)

Comment: I remember this being one of the big gripes about 10spd doubletap when it first came out in the mid? late? 2000's. I had Rival back then. Despite this, I *really* like Rival 10 spd

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a complete solution, but here's an imperfect workaround. When you go to downshift while in the lowest gear, you'll find that you can only push it over one click. Release the shift lever, then immediately press and release it two clicks to shift back down.

When you do this, the chain will disengage from the sprocket for about a quarter revolution, but won't actually move over to the next gear. You'll hear a little *clunk* and have to reduce your pedaling torque for a moment, but it isn't as disruptive as a complete gear shift.